# Include javascript libraries scoped

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, zepto

I'm creating a website widget. One where users can include a javascript file into their websites, and my widget will appear on their site.

**The problem:**
I want to use zepto.js and backbone.js, but what if the user who includes my widget is already using backbone, and maybe with jquery?

I want my libraries to be scoped, so they will not interfere with whatever the user might have running.

I have no clue how to to this but this is a suggestion to clarify what i want:

```
window.myWidgetSuperScope = function Backbone () {
  //include backbone.js here
}
```

Comment: How do you include backbone.js, using jquery or what? Any script included using jquery are set on global scope, using globalEval() method.

Comment: Right now i just include it in the head section of my html. <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Google and Facebbok with their +/like buttons resolves this using an `iframe`.
But it really depends on what your widget will be doing.
If it needs to interact and modify the page in which it is included, then you've to deal with what there could be on the page. Like using the already included backbone version if any, or include your zepto and bb within a different namespace.

Comment: My widget will not interact with the page, it will only get some variables from window.

Comment: So an `iframe` is less painful from a developer point of view. The js which includes your widget should create the iframe element and add the variables you need to it (or pass them to the url).